# Checking a triplet (P, Q, R) is triangular

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

If a sorted array is given, where elements are represented as A[0],A[1],A[2] etc...
To check below condition,

```
A[P] + A[Q] > A[R],
A[Q] + A[R] > A[P],
A[R] + A[P] > A[Q]
```

we can write, for i=0;

```
if( A[i]+A[i+1]>A[i+2] && A[i]+A[i+2]>A[i+1] && A[i+2]+A[i+1]>A[i])
```

Also, we can reduce it to

```
if ( A[i] > A[i+2] - A[i+1])
```

I dont understand the math behind the reduced form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the arrays are filled with positive numbers.

The key is that the list is sorted in a non-decreasing manner.

We already know that 
$$A_{i+2}  \ge A_{i+1}$$ from the beginning and hence clearly, we have $$A_{i}+A_{i+2}>A_{i+1}$$

Similarly for the other condition.

Comment: thanks.... it was very simple. Now i get it